# Memory issue with meteor up (mup) on Digital Ocean

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I couldn't find existing posts related to my issue. On a Digital Ocean Droplet, mup setup went fine, but when I try to deploy, I get the following error. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
root@ts:~/ts-deploy# mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

Building Started: /root/TS/
Bundling Error: code=137, error:
-------------------STDOUT-------------------

Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.

-------------------STDERR-------------------
bash: line 1: 31217 Killed meteor build --directory /tmp/dc37af3e-eca0-4a19-bf1a-d6d38bb8f517
```

Below are the logs. node -v indicates I am using 0.10.31. How do I check which script is exiting with the error? Any other ideas? Thanks!

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #106
Meteor requires Node v0.10.29 or later.
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #107
Meteor requires Node v0.10.29 or later.
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #108

stepping down to gid: meteoruser
stepping down to uid: meteoruser
```

After I went back to an old backup of the DO Droplet, and re-ran mup setup and mup deploy, I now get this in the command line output

```
Building Started: /root/TS
Bundling Error: code=134, error:
-------------------STDOUT-------------------

Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.

-------------------STDERR-------------------
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory
bash: line 1:  1724 Aborted                 (core dumped) meteor build --directory /tmp/bfdbcb45-9c61-435f-9875-3fb304358996
```

and this in the logs:

```
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
Exception while invoking method 'login' TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove.service (app/server/accounts.js:7:26)
    at Object.Accounts.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1024)
    at Object.Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1189)
    at Package (packages/accounts-oauth/oauth_server.js:45)
    at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:383
    at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:186)
    at runLoginHandlers (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:380)
    at Meteor.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:434)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1594)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648
Exception while invoking method 'login' TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove.service (app/server/accounts.js:7:26)
    at Object.Accounts.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1024)
    at Object.Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1189)
    at Package (packages/accounts-oauth/oauth_server.js:45)
    at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:383
    at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:186)
    at runLoginHandlers (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:380)
    at Meteor.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:434)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1594)
    at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory issue stems from using DigitalOcean's $5 Droplet. To solve the problem, I [added swap](https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/digital-ocean-swap) to the server, as explained in detail below.

Create and enable the swap file using the dd command :

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=256k
```

“of=/swapfile” designates the file’s name. In this case the name is swapfile.

Next prepare the swap file by creating a linux swap area:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

The results display:

```
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 262140 KiB
no label, UUID=103c4545-5fc5-47f3-a8b3-dfbdb64fd7eb
```

Finish up by activating the swap file:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

You will then be able to see the new swap file when you view the swap summary.

```
swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        262140  0   -1
```

This file will last on the virtual private server until the machine reboots. You can ensure that the swap is permanent by adding it to the fstab file.

Open up the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Paste in the following line:

```
 /swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Swappiness in the file should be set to 10. Skipping this step may cause both poor performance, whereas setting it to 10 will cause swap to act as an emergency buffer, preventing out-of-memory crashes.

You can do this with the following commands:

```
echo 10 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
To prevent the file from being world-readable, you should set up the correct permissions on the swap file:

sudo chown root:root /swapfile 
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
```

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone looking to use this technique: [YMMV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329103/mup-deploy-killed-on-do-droplet-but-no-errors-in-logs)

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me by increasing the swap space to 1gb:

```
Make all swap off
sudo swapoff -a

Resize the swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024

Make swapfile usable
sudo mkswap /swapfile

Make swapon again
sudo swapon /swapfile
```